# Is there a way to get UID of the kube-system namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

In my project I need to use UID of the kube-system namespace, but could not find a way to get it. Is it possible to retrieve this?

Answer (score 3):

`...UID of the kube-system namespace...`

kubectl get namespace kube-system --output jsonpath={.metadata.uid}

Answer (score 0):

If you need an API way, you can use k8s APIs to get the same:

```
curl -s http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system | jq .metadata.uid
```